# Postgresql full text search with TypeOrm

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

There is some way to handle full text search with Postgres and TypeOrm. I've seen some examples but they only work with Mysql. How can I get the equivalent of this but with Postgresql?

```
@Entity()
export class User {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: string;

    @Index({ fulltext: true })
    @Column("varchar")
    name: string;
}
```

And use query builder:

```
const searchTerm = "John";

const result = await connection.manager.getRepository(User)
            .createQueryBuilder()
            .select()
            .where(`MATCH(name) AGAINST ('${searchTerm}' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`)
            .getMany();
```

Comment: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3068

Comment: "*There is some way to handle full text search with Postgres and TypeOrm*" - how do you know that? Yes, `MATCH(name) AGAINST ('${searchTerm}' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` is definitely MySQL-specific syntax (and also an sql injection).

Comment: This issue makes no sense to me because I am very new on TypeOrm, I need a more complete example like the one in the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For case insensitive searches I usually use the [`ILIKE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html) PostgreSQL expression. eg;

```
const searchTerm = "John";

const result = await connection.manager.getRepository(User)
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .select()
  .where('name ILIKE :searchTerm', {searchTerm: `%${searchTerm}%`})
  .getMany();
```

Or if you had first and last name columns.

```
const result = await connection.manager.getRepository(User)
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .select()
  .where('first_name ILIKE :searchTerm', {searchTerm: `%${searchTerm}%`})
  .orWhere('last_name ILIKE :searchTerm', {searchTerm: `%${searchTerm}%`})
  .getMany();
```

Answer (score 34):

Here's an alternative using tsvector, where query is the input string.

```
      const songs = await getManager()
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .select('song')
        .from(Models.Song, 'song')
        .where(
          'to_tsvector(song.title) @@ to_tsquery(:query)',
          { query }
        )
        .getMany();
```

If you wish to include stop words (You, A, etc), and want partial matching.

```
      const songs = await getManager()
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .select('song')
        .from(Models.Song, 'song')
        .where(
          `to_tsvector('simple',song.title) @@ to_tsquery('simple', :query)`,
          { query: `${query}:*` }
        )
        .getMany();
```

If you also want to allow for multi word strings (with spaces).

```
      const formattedQuery = query.trim().replace(/ /g, ' & ');
      const songs = await getManager()
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .select('song')
        .from(Models.Song, 'song')
        .where(
          `to_tsvector('simple',song.title) @@ to_tsquery('simple', :query)`,
          { query: `${formattedQuery}:*` }
        )
        .getMany();
```

Comment: This is how primary a text based search should happen in postgres. The usuage of regular expresssion is fine but they highly affect the performance of the query. Using tsvector() and tsquery() is the postgre recommeded approach as well

Comment: does the formattedQuery have any risk of SQL injection?

Comment: I dont think so, but might be worth another stack overflow question entirely.

Answer (score 12):

For Full-Text Search (FTS), I would recommend you to use [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/textsearch.html) specific functions on the WHERE clause. The LIKE & ILIKE operators are too simple and too slow for a Full-Text Search. I suggest you also watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szfUbzsKvtE) video. It really explains clearly and easily on how to implement such a feature with PostgreSQL and at the last minutes, it shows how it implements it with Node.js.

I hope that helps! Please let me know if there is anything else I can help you with.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szfUbzsKvtE&ab_channel=BenAwad